# Angularjs: How to set Image data to IMG tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Please let me elaborate the issue.

I am fetching user profile pic by hitting an api that is returning image as data as shown below in the screen shot

[image]
[image]

I can not se the api url in the IMG tag src because I need to pass `access token` in the `headers` with the get request.

**Here is the code that I am doing**

```
vm.getDp = function () {
    if (vm.userDetails.hasDp) {
        userService.getProfilePic(vm.userDetails.id, vm.userDetails.profileImageUrl, accessToken)
            .then(function (data) {
                $("#theDp").attr('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data);
            }, function (error) {

            });
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MaartenBicknese I am not able to set `image data` to `img` tag. How to set Image data that I am getting from API to IMG tag?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AngularJS, lets stop using jQuery to do our stuff. You can use the [`ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive to bind scope variables to the `src` attribute of an image.

So by preparing your HTML with the directive

```
<img ng-src="{{vm.img_data}}" alt="Description" />
```

You can then show your image by setting the retrieved data.

```
vm.getDp = function () {
    if (vm.userDetails.hasDp) {
        userService.getProfilePic(vm.userDetails.id, vm.userDetails.profileImageUrl, accessToken)
            .then(function (data) {
                vm.img_data = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data;
            }, function (error) {

            });
    }
}
```

To prevent showing a broken image you could wrap your `img` element in a [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive.

**Example**
Note the small red dot, which is the picture.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('ImageShower', ImageShower);

function ImageShower($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.image_data = false;
  vm.title = 'Image Shower';

  activate();

  function activate() {
    vm.image_data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ImageShower as vm">
  <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>
  <img ng-src="{{vm.image_data}}" alt="Description" />
  <p>{{vm.image_data}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that is not working either. I have added 1 more screen shot in the question please check.

Comment: As you can see in the new example, this method works. Can you tell some more about your screenshot, the problems seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: that red dot is not the picture but it is something else. (a button to capture picture) Please let me know what can I tell you more about the screen shot

Comment: I am not sure if the data is base64 or not its just  an image.

Comment: Judging from your screenshot you're actually getting the binary version of your image. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/2637098 on how to convert that to Base64